# Load the values from the resource file based on the user/DB input in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, dynamic

```
    @foreach (var panelGroup in Model.GetPanelGroups())
    {
    <div id="sm-form-group-@panelGroup" class="form-inline grid-options">
        <!-- subtitle -->
        <h3>@DashboardExtensions.GetPanelGroupName((int)panelGroup, Model.GetPluginNameForPanelGroup((int)panelGroup)) @Resources.StringPanels</h3>
        <div class="tile-options">
        @foreach (var preference in Model.GetPreferenceForGroup((int)panelGroup))
        {
            <div class="tile-group" data-tiletype="@preference.Panel">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Values[(int)preference.Panel], new { @id = String.Format("id-sm-checkbox-dashboard-{0}", (int)preference.Panel) })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PluginIds[(int)preference.Panel], new { @id = String.Format("id-sm-hidden-pluginId-{0}", (int)preference.Panel) })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PanelIds[(int)preference.Panel], new { @id = String.Format("id-sm-hidden-panelId-{0}", (int)preference.Panel) })
                <label for="id-checkbox-dashboard-@preference.Panel">@preference.Panel</label>
            </div>
        }
        </div>
    </div>
    }
```

In this code, `@preference.Panel` is getting retrieved from DB as Id. I need to pick the value from the resource files based on the id that is getting displayed in the label section.
Something like

> String.Format(@Resources.preference_{0},@preference.Panel).

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried adding key values like Panel_1,Panel_2 in resource files and in the CSHTML file i tried adding                      <label for="id-checkbox-dashboard-@preference.Panel">@String.Format(Resources.Panel_{0}, preference.Panel)</label>.This didn't work out.Is there any technique to dynamically call the resource files key values?

Comment: Your problem is getting the proper resource, not displaying labels. What have you tried to get the resource?

Comment: String.Format(Resources.Panel_{0}, preference.Panel).I tried something in this way only.But its not working.Since i'm new to this i dont have any other ideas.